# Capture data grid event from one user control to another

Tags: winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I am working on a Windows Forms application. My application contains a main container where I load the user controls at run time.

I have one user control which contains a data grid. I have another user control which contains another data grid and a tab control.

What I need is that when a row is selected in grid view 1 (of user control 1) then based on the ID of selected row I will fatch the value from data base and bind the data to gridview 2 (of user control 2). And by default first row of the gridview 2 will be selected and based on selected row data will be populated in Tab control (of user control 2).

Can someone please provide me basic code of event creation, raising and handling between user control. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these approaches:

[Hierarchical data binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial#hierarchical)

[Hierarchical data binding with a DataSet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial#hierarchical_dataset)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.